# How to properly cast to a negative number in Rust?

Tags: rust, casting

In Rust, this code is valid :

```
let signedInt: i32 = 23*-1;
```

However, this is not :

```
let unsignedInt: u16 = 2;
let signedInt: i32 = unsignedInt*-1;
```

Which makes sense, as Rust tries to interpret -1 as if it were of the same type as `unsignedInt`.
So casting is needed. However, said casting becomes quite ugly when using more types :

```
-((unsignedInt*320) as f32)
```

Doing this is needed, as `-(unsignedInt*320)` is an invalid expression. But the code above is basically unreadable, and I was wondering what was the best way of making it both valid Rust and human-readable.

Comment: Idiomatic Rust favors explicitness over terse syntax... _generally_. That's just part of the language design philosophy, and something you'll get used to as you write more Rust. The idea is that it helps with code clarity in many cases: and, in my own experience, it does.

Answer (score 3):

Rust requires explicit casts because it's a common source of bugs in other languages like C. Generally you should avoid `as`, and use `from` or `into` instead if possible, otherwise `try_from`/`try_into`. The main exception is int<->float casts which are only generally possible with `as` at the moment.

Because all numbers in `u16` can be represented in `i32`, your second example can be written as:

```rust
let unsignedInt: u16 = 2;
let signedInt = i32::from(unsignedInt) * -1;
```

Your third example can be written the same way:

```rust
let unsignedInt: u16 = 2;
let float = -f32::from(unsignedInt * 320);
```

But note that for larger integers, you have to use `as` casts instead:

```rust
let unsignedInt: u32 = 2;
let float = -((unsignedInt * 320) as f32);
```

Comment: To be more harsh, this behavior of Rust is because of [XKCD 568](https://xkcd.com/568) panel 2.  The compiler is *forcing* you to explain *exactly* what you intend to do, rather than guessing that you "knew" the implications of multiplying two numbers that don't necessarily have a way to represent both cleanly "automagically" (that's not a typo).